# Proving bounded gradient for composite function

Tags: inequality, vector-analysis, lipschitz-functions, function-and-relation-composition, smooth-functions

I have a non-convex bounded function $h$ that is L-smooth and it has bounded gradient, i.e. $\|\nabla h(x)\| \leq \sigma^2, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Define the function $f(y) = \exp(\alpha \times h(y))$ where $\alpha > 0$. Can we show that $f$ is a smooth function with bounded gradient?

I'm focusing on showing the bounded gradient property as I believe this gives the smoothness using the mean value theorem. I know that $\nabla f(y) = \alpha \nabla h(y) \exp(\alpha \times h(y))$.
What I did so far is the following:
$$ \|\nabla f(y)\| \leq \alpha \sigma^2 \exp(\alpha \times h(y))$$

Since $h$ is bounded, i.e. $|h(y)| \leq M$ then I can write:
$$ \|\nabla f(y)\| \leq \alpha \sigma^2 \exp(\alpha M)$$

Would this be sufficient to say that $f$ is a smooth function with a bounded gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure the result you want to prove is true.
If $h$ is the identity function (which is convex though), $h$ is smooth with bounded gradient and $f$ has not bounded gradient.

We can think of a non convex function which shows that your claim does not hold, for example $h(x)=x$ if $x\geq 0$ and $h(x)=2x$ if $x\leq 0$. I am aware it is not differentiable at $0$ but this gives some intuition that your result cannot be proved.

If you want a differentiable function you can use a quadratic part around $0$, like that:

\begin{equation}
  h(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      x & \text{if } x\geq 1\\
      -\dfrac{1}{4}(x^2-6x+1) & \text{if } -1\leq x\leq 1\\
      2x & \text{if } x\leq -1
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

[image]

Of course for $x\geq 1$, $f$ has not bounded gradient.

Comment: do you think we could make further assumptions on $h$ to make the result valid for $f$? how about assuming that $h$ is bounded?

Comment: I'm editing the question by adding the bounded assumption on $f$.

Comment: if $h$ is bounded then $f$ has bounded gradient, this is obvious, but this does not directly imply that $f$ is smooth (it implies that $f$ is Lipschitz only). However if your function is twice differentiable you can prove that $f$ has bounded second derivative